# UWP to MariaDB using MySQL Connector Net 6.7.9

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp, mariadb

I've been trying to get some initial code working before I start working on my app.
I have had this working maybe a year ago so something tells me there is an update/version issue.
But any help is good so.

I have a raspberry pi set up with apache, MariaDB, php etc etc. I have a simple webpage running so apache is fine, I have another webpage that pulls data from a table so MariaDB is fine (fine-ish, given my issue). I have myphpadmin set up and can log in create new db's and users etc.

Now I would like to have a UWP app interact with a db hosted on my pi. I created a new user with SELECT and INSERT only for a specific db (hopefully this reduces security issues but I'm new so maybe I'm wishing).

I also then found the mariadb config file and commented the bind-address line. The skip-networking line is no longer in the file so just ignored that. (this is what the docs say to allow remote connections).

I have opened port 3306 on my router, and I also have a domain name and use no-ip but I assume this is all fine as apache runs fine. Saw someone talking about SSH, I changed my ssh port but I don't think that would be the issue.

Then the UWP.

Last time I tried this I had to use MySQL Connector Net 6.7.9 as newer versions didn't work with RT. So I have added this to the project references.

Now for simple testing the connection I have a button and TextBlock, click the button to attempt connecting and output the exception/result.
Have tried conn string builder as well as just a straight forward string, neither work.

```
    private void ConnectDatabase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnString;
        MySqlConnection Conn;

        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder Csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        Csb.Server = "http://rnd-domain.me";
        Csb.Port = 3306;
        Csb.UserID = "usr";
        Csb.Password = "passwd";
        Csb.Database = "testdb";


        ConnString = "server=http://rnd-domain.me;database=testdb;uid=usr;pwd=passwd;";
        Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString);

        try
        {
            Conn.Open();
            DbUpdateText.Text = "connected";
            Conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            DbUpdateText.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

When I click the button the ex.Message is 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'.
There are no errors thrown with the app, just this unhelpful message.

I've googled this and wasted 80% of my sunday trying to get this working. I've added sslmode=none, charset=utf8, port=3306. I tried using server=localhost or using my current ip and even using my mariadb master user (not root).

What could be the issue?

Thanks.

Edit:
I just used the pi's internal IP and got a new ex.Message, understood this one about SSl, added sslmode=none and all is working.

So now its just getting around the domain name issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string isn't quite right.

You probably want this:

```
    server=rnd-domain.me;database=testdb;uid=usr;pwd=REDACTED;
```

It doesn't make sense to mention `http://` in a MySQL connection string, because the connection doesn't use the HTTP protocol. Rather it uses the MySQL protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the offering, however removing the http:// made no difference and in fact caused the app to freeze. Also passwd was my generic nonsense password :)

Comment: You could check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases#add-a-connection-string) connect string.

Comment: Hi yes I think because the pc running visual studio and the pi hosting the db are both on the same lan it doesn't like the full dns. Using the internal pi IP and it all works and I can get data from a table. I would guess when the app runs outside of the lan the full dns would work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using a pc (client) and raspi (server) both inside the home network.

When I changed the host to the internal IP of the raspi it all worked fine.